# Keep non active images to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have images that when you click will grow. However, the images not being clicked move to the bottom of the containing div when an image grows. Example: http://jsbin.com/losuniti/1/edit?html,css,output  How can I force the non clicked images to just stay at the top of the div? I've tried using

```
    .images img { top: 0 !important; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add vertial-align:top to the images img selector:

```
    .images img {
      vertical-align:top;
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
         top: 0 !important;}
```

I think that does what you want.